# C++ Cannot Remove File in Windows Environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wanted to give Microsoft Visual Studio IDE a shot after working on XCODE for a while. I was able to import all my code, but cannot figure out why the `remove` function does not work in Windows environment. The file is being written to `C:\Users\Linus\source\proj\proj` the same location of my project. I am confused because my program can write to and read from files, but can't remove them. I didn't have any problems in XCODE removing a file, even when I changed its scheme (files were written to another directory and removal worked fine). I don't have much experience with Visual Studio and would really appreciate any advice on setting up my project correctly so I can remove files.

project.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream newFile("newFile.txt");
    if (remove("newFile.txt") != 0) {
        cout << "removed file" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Project Directory

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Linus\source\repos\proj\proj

06/06/2018  11:49 PM    <DIR>          .
06/06/2018  11:49 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/07/2018  08:03 AM    <DIR>          Debug
06/06/2018  11:41 PM               288 proj.cpp
06/06/2018  11:49 PM             8,362 proj.vcxproj
06/06/2018  11:48 PM             1,519 proj.vcxproj.filters
06/06/2018  11:41 PM               165 proj.vcxproj.user
06/07/2018  08:03 AM                16 firstHalf.txt
06/07/2018  08:03 AM                 0 newFirstHalf.txt
06/07/2018  08:03 AM                 0 newSecondHalf.txt
06/07/2018  08:03 AM                28 random.txt          //can't remove this
06/07/2018  08:03 AM                14 secondHalf.txt
06/06/2018  11:41 PM               602 stdafx.cpp
06/06/2018  11:41 PM               642 stdafx.h
06/06/2018  11:41 PM               630 targetver.h
              12 File(s)         12,266 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  37,871,968,256 bytes free
```

Comment: Close the file before deleting it

Comment: Windows is no Unix. An open file is locked, you cannot remove it, cannot open it in another process etc. This has nothing to do with C++ or MSVC specifically.

Comment: You don't check `errno` either to see why it failed

Comment: Why do you open the file and then delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac/Linux/Unix you can delete an open file because the filesystems are clever enough to know that when an open file is deleted not to delete the actual disk file until the last handle is closed.

Windows doesn't have this concept so generally files that are open in a program cannot be deleted (although generally they can still be renamed).

To fix your code close the stream before you remove the file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream newFile("newFile.txt");
    if (!newFile) {
        cout << "file not opened" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    newFile.close();
    if (remove("newFile.txt") == 0) {
        cout << "removed file" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: even this may not always work especially in the presence of virus checkers which may have opened your file before you call remove.

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate on what a handle is? What would happen if you delete the disk file before the last handle is closed?

Comment: By a file handle I mean a reference to a file which is given to a process when it opens that file. On Unix files have reference counts so whilst you might be able to delete the file name the actual file isn't removed from the disk until the last handle closes and the reference count reaches zero. On Windows you can't delete the file before the last handle is closed.

Comment: oh ok, so the actual file isn't deleted after all in UNIX until the program ends if there is no `close`?

Comment: yep, it wont be visible on the filesystem but its still on the disk

Comment: `remove()` returns nonzero on failure.